# Edit "Not Available" Page

Tags: wp-admin

Hi I've recently edited my /wp-admin page and it is now hiding from mysite.tld/wp-admin

But…

Is it possible for me to edit the page "Not Available" to static HTML or 404 page?

Since I'm trying to hide the fact that I'm using WordPress. Of course there is still lots of trace. But I'm trying my best to hide it.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc1el.jpg)

Comment: have you got any error in console?

Comment: Nope, I can go inside wp-admin with another link, it will show "Not Available" on the original mysite.tld/wp-admin. And I want to hide that